How to apply changes of cron jobs inside /etc/cron.d/filename?
I've changed /etc/cron.d/filename and have added there one new job.
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/scripts/scriptname.sh

But this job is not executed.
Cron restarting doesn't help.

Your crontab entry:
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/scripts/scriptname.sh

What's missing here is the special user field that is found in non-personal crontabs (/etc/crontab and the files under /etc/cron.d/).  This should be the 6th field, before the command, and should be the username of the user that should execute the command.  For example, if the user is myuser:
* * * * * myuser /bin/bash /root/scripts/scriptname.sh

This is equivalent to myuser adding your initial crontab entry to their personal crontab via the crontab -e command.
Once the formatting of the schedule is corrected, it will be active. There is no need to restart the cron daemon.
